# How to get rspec output to quickfix window in vim

Tags: vim, rspec

I have a lot of tests to fix, I'd like to be able to use something like [vim-rspec](https://github.com/thoughtbot/vim-rspec) to run my rspec tests, and then pipe the output back to the quickfix window so I can fix my tests inside of vim.    That plugin is very convenient, but doesn't [seem to want to offer that feature](https://github.com/thoughtbot/vim-rspec/issues/39)

I'd be happy with running something like `:!rspec` but that just goes to the terminal and doesn't put anything in quickfix.

Comment: It looks kinda complicated, but if this helps, great: 

http://fweepcode.blogspot.com/2013/03/faster-tdd-with-rspec-vim-and-quickfix.html

Answer (score 4):

You can try Tim Pope's vim-dispatch plugin: https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch

Once installed, rspec can be run synchronously with '**:Dispatch rspec**' or asynchronously with '**:Dispatch! rspec**'. The results will be populated to quickfix window, pressing 'enter' on the error detail will navigate to matching line in source file.

Here's a post explaining more about that plugin: http://tilvim.com/2014/03/13/dispatch.html

Comment: fwiw i use `nmap <leader>r :Dispatch! rspec %<CR>` in my `.vimrc` file to give me an easy way to rerun my current test file